# Find problems causing overload of program

Tags: c#, performance, flash, memory, memory-leaks

I have a bot that plays a flash game automatically. I have loaded the flash object through an extended WebView a friend coded for me and I use native imports to send click messages to the handle. Everything works good for about 30 minutes. After that the bot, GUI and whole mechanism starts getting slower and slower, lagging more and more, eventually ending up clicking totally different coordinates. I suspect there's a memory leak or performance issue in my source code. How can I find that out or fix it?

Comment: Run a memory profiler on it.

Comment: I tried doing so with Telerik JustTrace, but I couldn't really come to an idea. Going to give RedGate's Memory Profiler a try now.

Comment: I use Ants, it's nice

Comment: Are you using unsafe code?

Comment: Yes I am. This is how I import the native functions. @DonBoitnott I tried running ANTS Memory Profiler but I have no clue what to actually look for. I see that 96% of the memory is used by unmanaged code and that the largest class is the string class.

Comment: I used Adobe Scout to debug my own memory leaks and found it to be pretty nice http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/ still takes some poking around but ultimately was able to figure out where my leaks were based on the function stack calls